# How to resolve "speech_recognition.exceptions.UnknownValueError" error when no voice recording is made?

Tags: speech-recognition

I have a loop that runs for 2 minutes. Within this loop, I ask for user input or record their voice. If I provide any input or record anything, the output displays the recorded voice. However, an error occurs when I do not speak or record anything. How can I resolve this issue? I have included my code and the error message below:

**My Code:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
from simple_colors import *

t_end = time.time() + 60 * 2
while time.time() < t_end:

    #################################
    # Recording User voice

    # initialize the recognizer
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        start_time = time.time()
        WaitingTime=10
        print("Speak for 10 seconds.............\n")
        
        # read the audio data from the default microphone
        audio_data = r.record(source, duration=WaitingTime)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if elapsed_time > 10:
            print("Recording STOPPED!!!\n")
        print("Recognizing user voice.............\n")

        # Convert speech to text
        text = r.recognize_google(audio_data) # Recording in English
        print('User Question is:',text,"?\n")
```

**Error Message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\4136\Desktop\AI Operator\Python\test5.py", line 26, in 
text = r.recognize_google(audio_data) # Recording in English
File "C:\Users\4136\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 728, in recognize_google
if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.exceptions.UnknownValueError

***My expectation: I expect that if I do not speak or record anything, it will ask the question again or prompt for recording until the loop is completed.***

Answer (score 0):

put the whole of logic inside a while loop, that'll work. This will solve your error. As per what you are expecting, you can achieve this with voice activity detector (pydub or webrtcvad for example). the recording can be initiated when voice is detected. If silence is detected, you can ask questions for recording. Let me know if this helped you.